# Query a dataset applying filter on month and year in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following dataset

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    the_debt_id varchar(6) NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_paid date NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_due date NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ('LMUS01', '2019-05-03', '2019-05-02'), 
       ('LMUS01', '2019-06-03', '2019-06-02'), 
       ('LMUS01', '2019-07-01', '2019-07-02'), 
       ('LMUS02', '2019-05-03', '2019-05-07'), 
       ('LMUS02', '2019-06-07', '2019-06-07')
```

And I want to query this dataset by filtering only the rows where `the_debt_paid` is in June 2019.

The expected result is:

```
the_debt_id    the_debt_paid     the_debt_due
LMUS01         2019-06-03        2019-06-02
LMUS02         2019-06-07        2019-06-07
```

I tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE EXTRACT(month, the_debt_paid) = 6
```

But I don't know how apply with the year which is 2019. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Syntax of extract is wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE EXTRACT('month' from  the_debt_paid) = 6 
and EXTRACT('year' from the_debt_paid)=2019
```

You can write your query like this also:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE (EXTRACT(month from  the_debt_paid), EXTRACT('year' from the_debt_paid))=(6,2019)
```

you can compare month and year by using `extract`
[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c9d4ab34a823c31a8167079682efbcfb)

Answer (score 5):

Use direct date comparisons!

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table 
WHERE the_debt_paid >= '2019-06-01' AND
      the_debt_paid < '2019-07-01';
```

Using functions on dates is bad from multiple perspectives.

- First, it is less readable.  I find that explicit date constants are more easily understood and maintained over time.
- Second, it prevents the use of indexes on the columns, in almost all cases.
- Third, it makes the query much harder to optimize, because statistics on the expression are not as accurate as statistics on the column itself.

Comment: Verifiably true.  Despite modern RDMSes being quite smart about statement equivalency, extract prevents the use of an index.  However if you must use EXTRACT you can leverage a function index, which may be ever so slightly faster than the above for querying.